# Rendering field with the help of functions

Tags: entities, hooks

I have a field and I can render its value in a such way:

```
<?php print $entity1->field_list_of_options['und'][0]['safe_value'];?>
```

But I have many different entities at the page so I want to hide the following tail in a function in order to get something like this:

```
<?php print $entity1->Get_list(); ?>
```

How can I do it? I tried to get predefined functions in a custom module but couldn't find a proper hook. How can I handle this problem?

I wrote the following in order to collect my "tails":

`function mymodulename_getText($entityId,$field){
    return $entityId->$field."['und'][0]['safe_value']";
}`

And so, I use it in such way:

`<?php 
$enityId = 2;
$entity2 = entity_load_single('entitytype', $entityId); ?>
<p><?php print getText($entity2, field_list_of_options); ?></p>`

But I don't know how to implement my function to my custom module in order to get it in node's body where I want to print it using PHP Filter.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to add a method to your `$entity1` object. as opposed to some general purpose function (e.g. `mytheme_get_list($entity1)`)?

Comment: @ShawnConn, The reason is following: I use ECK module in order to create custom entities, so, I'am afraid, I wouldn't be able to get my entities in a proper way by using this function. I get the entity array by the function `entity_load_single($type, $id)` and then render proper fields and their values from it. At the end, I have 5 different entities at the same page, so I decided to work this way. What can you advise me?

Comment: If the goal here is solely rendering the entity data field data, you might better off defining a template function that renders the markup and injects it into template variables. I don't know your entire use case so maybe extending the entity object with your own custom method makes sense.

Comment: @ShawnConn, could you please explain this approach more clearly, I don't get an idea...

Comment: All I'm suggesting is it might be easier to add a template function to your theme to iterate/print over a multi-fielded entity rather than extending the entity with your own custom method.

Comment: @ShawnConn, could you please provide an example?... I don't really understand, how can I bind theme and entity template in this way...

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for your approach would be:

```
function mymodulename_getText($entityId,$field){
    return $entityId->$field['und'][0]['safe_value'];
}
```

I suggest to sanitize that with a isset().

Comment: I get the following warnings: 
    `Warning: Illegal string offset 'und' in mypages_getText() (line 113 of /sites/all/modules/mypages/mypages.module).
    Warning: Illegal string offset 'safe_value' in mypages_getText() (line 113 of /sites/all/modules/mypages/mypages.module).
    Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in pages_getText() (line 113 of /sites/all/modules/mypages/mypages.module).
`

Comment: So I have the following code: `function mypages_getText($entityId, $select_field){
  return $entityId->$select_field['und'][0]['safe_value'];
}` and I call this function in a such way: `if (module_exists('mypages')) {print mypages_getText('2', 'field_test_field'); }` what do I do wrong?

Comment: If you call your func with '2' as $entityId, you need to load the real entity object, '2' is just a string ("non-object")! I.e. with node_load(array("nid" => $entity_id)).

Comment: is it impossible to do with entity_load_single()?